# Neighbourhood of a point

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone explain what the neighbourhood actually is? I can not make a clear picture of it in my mind. I have searched it everywhere but can't get my answer. I'm confused about the differences between neighbourhood, interior points, and open set.

Answer (score 2):

In a metric space $X$, a neighbourhood of a point $a$ is a set containing
$a$ which also contains all points near enough to $a$; more precisely it's a set $A$ such that for some radius $r>0$, every point at distance less
than $r$ from $a$ is within $A$. Even more precisely, $A$ is a neighbourhood of $A$ if
$$\{x\in X:d(x,a)<r\}\subseteq A$$
for some $r>0$ (where $d$ denotes the distance function in the metric space $X$).

For instance, if $X=\Bbb R$ then $A$ is a neighbourhood of $a$ if
$(a-r,a+r)\subseteq A$ for some $r>0$.

Answer (score 0):

In a space $X$

A *neighborhood* is a set of points.  Given a point $x \in X$ a neighborhood *of $x$* are all the points in $X$ within a certain distance $r$ from $x$.  Your text may have different notation but I can state the neighborhood $N_r(x) = \{w \in X| d(x,w) < r\}$.  If our space where $\mathbb R^2$ and our distance function were $d((x,y),(v,u)) = \sqrt {(v-x)^2 + (u-y)^2}$ then then neighborhoo $N_{.0001}((2,3))$ would be the interior of a circle of radius $.0001$ and center $(2,3)$ (it would include all the points on the *interior* of the circle; none on the boundary).  But you should not really on that image.  In difference spaces the "distance" can be very different and the resulting set can be very different.  But a neighborhood is always the set of all the points in space $X$ within a certain distance of a point $x$.

Given a set of points $A$ and an element point $a \in A$.  We say that $a$ is an *interior point* if we can find a neighborhood of $a$ so that all the points in the neighborhood are in $A$.  So for example if $A$ is the rectangle (interior and edges) going from $(0,0)$ to $(0,2)$ to $(3,2)$ to $(3,0)$ and $a=(.001, 1.99)$ then $a$ is an interior point of $A$ because if we take the neighborhood of all the points in $X$ that are within $.01$ distance of $a$, every point will be a point of $A$. $a$ is "inside" $A$.  But the point $b = (0, .4)$ is not an interior point.  If we take any distance $\delta$ the point $c=(0-\delta, .4)$ will be within a distance of $\delta$ but $c \not \in A$.

We call a set *open* if every point in the set is an interior point.  That means for every point in the set, there is some distance (maybe very small) so that all the points in space within that distance are all in the set.  If the set has a "sharp edge" to it, none of those points on the edge are interior.  And the set isn't open.

Note: that a neighborhood, itself, must be an open set.